# function title($_GET["page"]) always returning empty string

Tags: php

This doesn't seem to work correctly for me, it always returns an empty string. I could not find the error that I made.

```
function title($page){
    $i=0;
    $title="";
    foreach ($page as $c){
        if ($i===0){
            ucfirst($c);
        }
        if ($c=="_"){
            $c=" ";
        }
        $i++;
        array_push($title,$c);
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: see link: .../index.php?page=home
it's just a function that prettyfies the page var.
I call it in the <title></title> tag.

Comment: You want to capitalize the first letter and replace underscores by spaces?

Comment: Is `$page` supposed to be an array or a string? You can't `foreach` over a string (despite being able to reference characters via `[]`). Something makes me think you ought to turn up error reporting... `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`... especially since `$title` is initialized as a string but you are attempting to `array_push()` onto it which will issue an `E_WARNING`.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the function.

Comment: Ahh, it is a string. I thought it worked that way, how should I turn it into an array then?

Comment: @TristanŠneider: You don't need to loop through the characters. [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/ucfirst) returns a string with the first character of string capitalized -- a loop is not required. See [*towr*'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20599784/1438393) below.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function title($page)
{
  return ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $page));
}
```